# how to stop constant animations

Tags: jquery, animation, constants

Look at my codes here please : http://jsfiddle.net/FVcJz/7/

when we hover on the text, we see an animation.
if we hover mouse 5 times on the text, the box will be animated 5 times.
how to set a code which prevents 4 remained animations when the first animation is not finished yet ?!
I mean to have animation only when the animation in not in progress by the previous hover ..
so then, when we hover 5 times on the text, the animation will be ran 1 time only ( if the 4 hovers are before animation ending )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use the stop method..

```
$(function () {

$(".tt").hover(function(){

    $(".bb").stop().animate({width:'150px'}, 500);  

},function() {

    $(".bb").stop().animate({width:'100px'}, 500);  


});     
});
```

​

Comment: I think I explained my question in bad way..
I mean, when you hover 3 times on the text, the box's width will become 150px and then 100px 3 times. I want it to happen 1 time when you hover N times during the box animation.
better explain :
I want the hover effect to become disabled during the animation and when the animation is finished, to become enabled..

Comment: mean a thing like this? `$(function () {
    
    $(".tt").hover(function(){
        if($(".bb").hasClass("started"))
            return;
        $(".bb").addClass("started");
        $(".bb").stop().animate({width:'150px'}, 500);  

    },function() {

        $(".bb").animate({width:'100px'}, 500,function(){
            $(".bb").removeClass("started");
        });  
        

    });     
        
});
​`

Answer (score 0):

First your code is not working so this is the correct code: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/FVcJz/2/)

If I click n times before the animation stops there is no problem with the animation. Which browser did you used?

Comment: sorry, here is the correct link --> http://jsfiddle.net/FVcJz/6/
I made some changes but still it doesn't work ..
first hover, and when box was animating, hover again. then hover when animation was finished. hover won't work ..

Comment: yes, when you hover n times before the animation stops, the box will animate n times.. I want to animate only once since the animation is not finished !!

Answer (score 0):

You can test with the jquery ':animated' selector if an animation is already in progress.

```
if (!$(".bb").is(':animated'))
{
  //no animation yet
  $(".bb").animate(...);
}
```

Comment: you didn't get my question. did you look at the link ?!

Comment: You didn't get my answer. You said "I mean to have animation only when the animation in not in progress" and I told how to check if an animation is in progress.